# How to optimize repetitive data in elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I am inserting very huge JSON in elastic search index. The problem is how can we optimize JSON in elasticsearch index. 
    e.g my json format looks like:

```
{
  "@context": "Context",
  "@type": "SessionEvent",
  "actor": {
    "@context": "Context",
    "@id": "554433",
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": null,
    "description": null,
    "extensions": {},
    "dateCreated": "2015-08-01T06:00:00.000Z",
    "dateModified": "2015-09-02T11:30:00.000Z"
  },
  "action": "action#LoggedIn",
  "object": {
    "@context": "Context",
    "@id": "viewer",
    "@type": "SoftwareApplication",
    "name": "ePub",
    "description": null,
    "extensions": {},
    "dateCreated": "2015-08-01T06:00:00.000Z",
    "dateModified": "2015-09-02T11:30:00.000Z"
  }
}
```

These type of JSON insert into elasticsearch in every seconds/minutes with the same actor or different actor with different actions. 
So how can i store these information in elastic search?

1. Currently storing as it is in elasticsearch?
2. Or can we store repetitive part of JSON in other index and put it's reference in the above JSON?

Please suggest which approach would be better.

Comment: this format looks okay'ish, even if you insert millions of records. is storage the concern?

Comment: No Storage is not concern . Yes millions of records will insert . I just want to know the correct approach . should i store the repetitive part of JSON in a separte index and link it to the main JSON or we can store entire JSON in index .